# About density matrices as both the vertices of a convex hull and the basis of a matrix space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, convex-hulls, quantum-information

Given $n$ density matrices $D_1, \dots, D_n$, that is, $D_i$ is positive semi-definite and $\operatorname{Tr}(D_i)=1$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$. Suppose that $D_1, \dots, D_n$ are linearly independent.

Denote by $\mathcal{S}:=\operatorname{span}\{D_1, \dots, D_n\}$ the linear space spanned by the given $n$ density matrices. Denote by $\mathcal{E}$ the set of all density matrices in $\mathcal{S}$.

Question: is $\mathcal{E}$ equal to the convex hull formed by the vertex set $\{D_1, \dots, D_n\}$? In other words, take an arbitrary element $A\in\mathcal{E}$, do we always have that $A=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i D_i$ where $\alpha_i$'s are all non-negative and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i=1$?

Comment: $(1+\varepsilon)D_1-\varepsilon D_2$ will be a density matrix for sufficiently small but positive $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Is this a counterexample? $$2\begin{bmatrix} 0.5 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0.5 & 0\\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Does the underlying state space have finite dimension $n$? Because if not then this is clearly false by the answer of Luftbahnfahrer.

Comment: @jd27 Yeah, I should have mentioned that the underlying state space have finite dimension, maybe say $N\geq n$.

Comment: Your question basically splits into 2 steps: (i) suppose the $D_i$ are of the form $\mathbf e_i\mathbf e_i^T$ [standard basis vectors].... can I argue that convex combinations generate all the density matrices in their span?  The answer is yes, though it contradicts the comment from @MichalAdamaszek .  (ii) What if I choose as "vertices" some matrices in the proper convex hull of (i) -- can I argue that the convex hulls are the same?  And it should be geometrically obvious that this is not true...  you would need some not convex affine combinations here.

Comment: @user8675309 This viewpoint is really helpful! Now I have a better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The [extreme points](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) of the set of [density matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix) are the pure states of the form $|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$.

If you have any collection of density matrices, $S=\{D_1, \dots, D_n\}$, any pure state $|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$ not in $S$ will not be in the convex hull $\mathcal{E}=\operatorname{conv}(S)$.

Edit: I realized after more carefully reading your question that I didn't directly answer it. To address your question a bit better, let $\operatorname{D}_n$ denote the set of $n\times n$ density matrices in $\operatorname{M}_n$, the space of $n\times n$ matrices, which has dimension $n^2$ as a vector space. You can choose $n^2$ linearly independent density matrices $$S=\{D_1, \dots, D_{n^2}\}\subset \mathrm{D}_n$$ that span the whole space, i.e. $\mathrm{span}(S)=\operatorname{M}_n$. Again, any pure state $|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$ not in $S$ will not be in the convex hull $\mathcal{E}=\operatorname{conv}(S)$, although it must be in the span of $S$.

Comment: You can not choose $n^2$ linearly independent density matrices, since they have to be self-adjoint.

Comment: @jd27 Luftbahnfahrer's answer should be true, see [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3511481/is-there-a-basis-for-the-space-of-density-matrices)

Comment: @Thinkpad interesting thanks. I think this only works if the base field is $\mathbb{C}$ though, because then the unitary matrices have the same dimension as $M_n$, but in the real case the symmetric ones only have dimension $1/2n(n-1)$. But i guess for density matrices only the case $\mathbb{C}$ is of real interest anyways.

Comment: @jd27 Thanks. This is a good catch anyway, I totally agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple counter example is the following (which is just the one you gave in the comments i realize now):
Let the base space have dimension $n=2$.
Let
$$D_1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$D_2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Clearly they are density matrices and linearly independent. Let
$$X = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Clearly $X$ is a density matrix. Since $X = 2 D_1 -D_2$ it is also contained in $\mathrm{span} \{D_1,D_2 \}$.
But there does not exist a $\lambda \in [0,1]$ so that $X = \lambda D_1 +(1-\lambda ) D_2$. Because to obtain the one at the index $(0,0)$ of $X$ we need that $\lambda = 2$. Which is clearly not allowed.