# About the kernel/null space of a quantum channel as a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, quantum-information

Consider the CPTP map $\Phi: M_n(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})$ that is not injective, which means the null space of $\Phi$ is non-trivial. My main question is, what can we say about the matrices in this null space?

By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3511481/is-there-a-basis-for-the-space-of-density-matrices), we can take a basis of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, denoted by $\{D_1,D_2,\dots,D_{n^2}\}$ where $D_i$'s are all $n\times n$ density matrices. Since $\Phi$ is not injective, we can get that $\operatorname{span}\{\Phi(D_1),\Phi(D_2),\dots,\Phi(D_{n^2})\}$ is a proper subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$. In other words, $\Phi(D_1),\Phi(D_2),\dots,\Phi(D_{n^2})$ are not linearly independent. So we have that
$$
\Phi(\alpha_1 D_1 + \alpha_2 D_2 + \cdots \alpha_{n^2} D_{n^2})=\alpha_1 \Phi(D_1) + \alpha_2 \Phi(D_2) + \cdots + \alpha_{n^2} \Phi(D_{n^2})=0
$$
for some $\alpha_i$'s that are not all zero. On the other hand, since $D_1,D_2,\dots,D_{n^2}$ are linearly independent, this implies that $\alpha_1 D_1 + \alpha_2 D_2 + \cdots \alpha_{n^2} D_{n^2}$ is a non-trivial element in the null space of $\Phi$.

Now let's look at this non-trivial element. **It is clearly Hermitian, and its trace is zero.** Of course, we can also use it to span a one-dimensional subspace of the null space. Is that all we can say about the matrices in the null space of $\Phi$?

**Edit**:
This proof may be not sufficient. But the above conclusion should be still correct, by the proof that I provided in the comments.

Comment: Other than the null space having vanishing trace, I don't think you can say much else about the null space in general.

Comment: Note that $M_n$ is a complex vector space, so the coefficients $\alpha_i$ can in general be complex, so the null space isn't Hermitian. Unless you are interested in the *real* vector space of nxn Hermitian matrices. Which also has dimension $n^2$.

Comment: @Luftbahnfahrer Thanks, I think you are right. But I still want to claim that there must be Hermitian matrices in the null space, by another proof. Consider a non-trivial element $A$ such that $\Phi(A)=0$. We can decompose $A$ into $\frac{A+A^*}{2}$ and $\frac{A-A^*}{2}$, which are Hermitian and skew-Hermitian, respectively. Note that the quantum channel $\Phi$ preserves Hermitianess and skew-Hermitianess. So we get that $\Phi(\frac{A+A^*}{2})$ and $\Phi(\frac{A-A^*}{2})$ are Hermitian and skew-Hermitian, respectively.

Comment: @Luftbahnfahrer Since $\Phi(\frac{A+A^*}{2})+\Phi(\frac{A-A^*}{2})=\Phi(A)=0$, it implies that $\left(\Phi\left(\frac{A+A^*}{2}\right)+\Phi\left(\frac{A-A^*}{2}\right)\right)^*=\Phi\left(\frac{A+A^*}{2}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{A-A^*}{2}\right)=0$. These two equalities give that one of $\frac{A+A^*}{2}$ and $\frac{A-A^*}{2}$ is in the null space and is non-trivial as well. Note that $\frac{A+A^*}{2}$ and $i\frac{A-A^*}{2}$ are both Hermitian, which completes the proof.

Comment: @Luftbahnfahrer Do you think this is all we can do? I wish there could be more information regarding the eigenvalues of this Hermitian matrix.

Comment: Since channels are Hermitian-preserving maps, then yes, as you observed, if the null space is nontrivial then it must contain a nontrivial Hermitian element. I don't think you can say much about the eigenvalues of null-space elements, though, without more specifics about the mapping.